# Django unable to find javascript static files, not rendering any styling

Tags: python, django

Feels like I'm missing something basic.

I'm just trying to make an django application of currently nothing but a login page using an html template that has its own css and js. But I'm having weird issues with the statements for linking my static files. No CSS styling is being rendered in my browser, and all of the javascript links get 404 file not found errors on my django server.

This is the `<head>` of `auth-login.html`.

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Login template from online</title>
        <!-- these aren't giving errors -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'assets/images/favicon.ico' %}">
        <link href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" id="bootstrap-style"/>
        <link href="{% static 'assets/css/icons.min.css' %}" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{% static 'assets/css/app.min.css' %}" id="app-style"  type="text/css" />

        <!-- these are giving errors for some reason -->
        <script src="{% static 'assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/libs/metismenu/metisMenu.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/libs/simplebar/simplebar.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/libs/node-waves/waves.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/js/app.js' %}"></script>
    </head>
```

In `settings.py`, this is how I'm specifying the static files location:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) # lpbs_demo/ 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

The Django project is currently structured with a project app called `lpbs_demo` and an app called `user_auth`. The `static/` folder is inside of the project app (`lpbs_demo/` folder). The `templates/` folder is at the project root directory, i.e. at the same level as manage.py

```
. lpbsnew/
+-- manage.py
+-- lpbs_env/ (venv)
+-- lpbs_demo/ (project app/package)
|   +-- __init__.py
|   +-- settings.py
|   +-- static/
|   +-- urls, asgi, wsgi ...
+-- user_auth/ (app)
|   +-- migrations/
|   +-- admin.py
|   +-- views.py
|   +-- models, tests, ...
+-- templates/
```

The project app urls.py in lpbs_demo/ looks like...

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from user_auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.userLogin, name='loginHome'),
    path('login', views.userLogin, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.userLogout, name='logout'),
    path('registration', views.userRegistration, name='registration'),
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

So with this, I'm not sure why only the Javascript files are generating errors and not being found, while the css files aren't generating errors but they're not rendering on the web page at all and I just see text in Times New Roman unstylized. It feels like there's something basic about linking static content that I must be missing.

I've called `python manage.py collectstatic` already as well.

edit: forgot to include templates/ folder location in the original post.

Edit 2: I got two suggestions on using `STATIC_ROOT` in settings.py but neither of them are changing the visuals I'm getting.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticFiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Several messages about potentially overwriting files come out.

Edit 3: It appears that the js files weren't getting copied via the `python manage.py collectstatic` command for some reason and I wasn't really sure why. But I made a new django project and was able to get that to work.

I'm no longer getting file not found errors, but I'm still not able to get any styling to render for some reason, so I made a new question.

[Django not serving static files and not stylizing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64988207/django-not-serving-static-files-and-not-stylizing-anything)

Comment: Where is your template folder?

Comment: @toRex just edited the original post. My `templates/` folder is at the same level as manage.py,  at the project root directory.

Comment: Add `STATIC_ROOT='static/'` then try again

Comment: @toRex didn't seem to work. I've gotten two answers on how to specify STATIC_ROOT but both lead to the same results.

Comment: How are you serving your app? ie are you using `runserver` or do you have it running behind an application server like `gunicorn`?

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` is being used to serve the app @JJK

Comment: What do you have set in your settings for `DEBUG`?

Comment: @JJK I just have DEBUG = True in settings.py

Comment: What else in your `settings.py` could be referencing `BASE_DIR`. Have you tried setting `BASE_DIR` to your project base directory as `lpbsnew`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225010/discussion-between-jjk-and-byron-smith).

Answer (score 0):

Move the `static` directory to the same level as the `manage.py` file.

`BASE_DIR` means the outermost folder of your project. So, this— `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`—would return a path like `lpbsnew/static/`. Django is trying to find a folder called `static` inside `lpbsnew` but it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I try to sort it out step by step (I personally had a hart time to sort out all the aspects of paths, urls, reverses and dev/deployment in a django app):

1. BASE_DIR should (by convention) point to the base folder which is lbpsnew in your case.

your assigment is doing that, but the comment is wrong! It does not point to lpbs_demo but to lbpsnew!

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) # lpbs_demo/
```

Btw, in most of the django projects lpbs_demo would be called lpbsnew (lbpsnew_project/lbpsnew/lbpsnew/settings.py)

2. STATIC_ROOT is the (absolute) target path where "collectstatic" will copy all your static files to.
   Please check after running "collectstatic" if  files are there.
3. it is a difference if you run your app with "runserver" or Apache etc. Why?

3a) because in Apache you could have Alias defined (which might be the problem) or a missing access right to the static folder.

3b) it makes a difference if you have DEBUG = True/False in your settings.py

... so please provide more details.

For Debugging:

- you can use the print(str(BASE_DIR)) to check directly in the seetings.py file.
- you can display the page source code in the browser and check what {% ulr ... %} has done in your html file

4. missing css (files, individual items) never lead to error messages to my experience. Style is then just missing. Carefull to empty Browser cache if you change css file content!