# Django not serving static files and not stylizing anything

Tags: python, django

I downloaded a template in the form  of a zip file on my machine. It has a file for a homepage, `auth-login.html`. If I load this on its own then it loads correctly, I see styling and I don't get any console errors.

But it seems like I can't get this template to load its css and styling in my Django project via `python manage.py runserver` with `DEBUG=true`. I'm trying to just get this on a development server and I haven't really been able to get past step 1. When I try to go to my application's home page, I see unstylized times new roman text in my browser. No styling loads on the page at all. I'm not getting server/console errors either.

My Django project is of the following structure

```
lpbsproject/ 
   project_root/
     staticFiles/ (STATIC_ROOT, where collectstatic copies to)
     project_app/
       settings.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py, asgi.py, __init__.py...        
     static/ (STATIC_URL, original location of static files)
       assets/ (this folder is copied/pasted from the template .zip)
         css/, js/, ...
     user_auth/
       migrations
       views.py
       admin.py, models.py, apps.py, test.py ...
     templates/
     manage.py
```

Here's the `<head>` of my html file with all the `<link>` and `<script>` statements. These currently aren't generating errors.

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Login template from online</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'assets/images/favicon.ico' %}">
        <link href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" id="bootstrap-style"/>
        <link href="{% static 'assets/css/icons.min.css' %}" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{% static 'assets/css/app.min.css' %}" id="app-style"  type="text/css" />
        <script src="{% static 'assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/libs/metismenu/metisMenu.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/libs/simplebar/simplebar.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/libs/node-waves/waves.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assets/js/app.js' %}"></script>
    </head>
```

In settings.py, this is how BASEDIR and the static file location are specified

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent # points to project_root/ directory
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticFiles')
```

There's ~1200 files in `project_root/static/assets/` and I am seeing these get copied into `project_root/staticFiles` from `python manage.py collectstatic`. Last night I was dealing with some weridness where none of the js files were getting copied via the collectstatic command.

and urls.py for curiosity sake...

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from user_auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.userLogin, name='loginHome'),
    path('login', views.userLogin, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.userLogout, name='logout'),
    path('registration', views.userRegistration, name='registration'),
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

So if `python manage.py collectstatic` is working... why am I still not able to see any styling at all? I'm not really sure what's going wrong here. It's felt way too difficult to just get a simple /static/ folder working for this project.

The terminal using `python manage.py runserver` isn't even showing requests for most of these css or js files.  I just see

```
[24/Nov/2020 12:48:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7194
[24/Nov/2020 13:25:39] "GET /static/assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.mi
n.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1883
[24/Nov/2020 13:25:39] "GET /static/assets/libs/metismenu/metisMenu.min.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1853
[24/Nov/2020 13:25:39] "GET /static/assets/libs/node-waves/waves.min.js.map HTTP /1.1" 404 1844
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get an answer when I posted about this on django forums.

No one here caught the html errors. I was inconsistently using `type=text/css` and `rel='stylesheet'`. Also `<link>` tags can end with `>`, not `/>`.